# Summary statistics by category using Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a datset with Scores and Categories and I would like to calculate the summary statistics for each of these categories. The data look something like this:

```
Category    Score    
AAAA        1
AAAA        3
AAAA        1
BBBB        1
BBBB        100
BBBB        159
CCCC        -10
CCCC        9
```

What I would then like would be something like this

```
Category    Count   Mean   Std   Min   25%   50%   75%   Max     
AAAA        
AAAA        
AAAA        
BBBB        
BBBB        
BBBB        
CCCC        
CCCC
```

I have been looking at using pandas with a combination of both `.groupby()` and `.describe()` like this

```
df.groupby('Category')['Score'].describe()
```

and this almost looks like what I want but when I come to view this as a Dataset, all of the stats are in the index. I would like the data to be in the form of a table so I can output it and create a visualization off of the back of it.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Could you clarify your question? It's not very clear what you are trying to achieve... What is wrong with `df.groupby('Category')['Score'].describe()`?

Comment: Apologies @MaxU. Hopefully I have clarified now :-)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

IIUC:

```
In [80]: df.groupby("Category")['Score'].describe().reset_index()
Out[80]:
  Category  count       mean        std   min    25%    50%     75%    max
0     AAAA    3.0   1.666667   1.154701   1.0   1.00    1.0    2.00    3.0
1     BBBB    3.0  86.666667  79.839422   1.0  50.50  100.0  129.50  159.0
2     CCCC    2.0  -0.500000  13.435029 -10.0  -5.25   -0.5    4.25    9.0
```